# Does Custom URL scheme works from other app other than web browser and email

Tags: android, ios

I understand I could use Custom URL scheme, like myapp://, so that when user click on the link, it will open my app.

Now, I know this will work when URL is invoked from webbrowser like Safari or mail. But would it work when user click on the link from for example SMS or whatsapp.

Also, what is the minimum Android version that support Custom URL scheme?

Comment: Both SMS and Whatsapp open the Link in Safari which in turn navigates to your app.

Comment: Thank you ... This answer my questions so you could post it as an answer.